# Exchange data between 2 connections efficently python sockets

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, udp, ports

I am working on a school project, and had an idea which i think will benifet me outside of school and is a bit over what school requires from me.

That is why i have a little lack of knowledge, everything regarding threads and dealing with multiple clients at once.

I had a few ideas, such as using UDP and wait for 2 connections and handle each one, but it made my code really messy and hard to follow, and really not efficent.

I would like to know if there is a good way to handle such a problem, and how.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a host then you are creating a new socket for each new client. With that in mind you can create a program that listens for connections and then create a new thread for each connection (to a client). Each thread can do multiple tasks, control the socket and/or exchange data with the main thread.

The same applies for you being a client: you can create a new thread for each new connection.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i think that you misunderstood me or i didnt understand you, i need 2 connections (in each thread), and then exchange data, but when i exchange data between 2 diffrent connections it makes my code messy, as i mentioned. I was curious if there is any way around it (openeing 2 socket objects). The client is not the problem, the main server is. In this program each client would have 2 sub-clients (2 connections, like 2 diffrent computers that need to communicate).

Comment: Do I understand you right? You are a host and you are only providing connection beetween the clients? If I am not right then please explain it to me a little better.

Comment: I have one main problem, when i wait for 2 UDP connections, whilst waiting for one of my threads to recieve data, it gets confused, data gets mixed up, and I have no idea how to solve, it. I hope it is a more specific problem, thank you for answering !

Comment: We have no idea why your data is getting mixed up. As the problem is probably in your code, we need to see it to understand what is going on and answer you. Your question does not provide enough informations for us to undserstand the situation. Please provide them.